# how to increase the number of pages comes in google search?

Tags: python, google-api

I am using [google search api](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/reference.html#_intro_fonje)
But by default it shows 4 and maximum 8 results per page. I want more results per page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `rsz=8` parameter to this [google search demonstration code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657570/google-search-from-a-python-app/1657597#1657597),
then use the `start=...` parameter to control which group of results you receive.

This, for example, gives you 50 results:

```
import urllib
import json
import sys
import itertools

def hits(astr):
    for start in itertools.count():
        query = urllib.urlencode({'q':astr, 'rsz': 8, 'start': start*8})
        url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&%s'%(query)
        search_results = urllib.urlopen(url)
        results = json.loads(search_results.read())
        data = results['responseData']
        if data:
            hits = data['results']
            for h in hits:
                yield h['url']
        else:
            raise StopIteration


def showmore(astr,num):
    for i,h in enumerate(itertools.islice(hits(astr),num)):
        print('{i}: {h}'.format(i=i,h=h))

if __name__=='__main__':
    showmore(sys.argv[1],50)
```

Comment: The question is, as far as I understand, how to get *more* than 8 results in one query.

Comment: Oops, I misunderstood the question... This post will self-destruct in 30 seconds...

Comment: list index out of range i am getting

Comment: @alis: If you save the above script as `test.py`, then run it like this: `test.py searchterm`. If you just run `test.py`, then yes, you get a `IndexError: list index out of range` exception.