# access to google with python

Tags: python

how i can access to google !!

i had try that code

```
urllib.urlopen('http://www.google.com')
```

but it's show message `prove you are human` or some think like dat

some people say try user agent !! i dunno !

Comment: To do google searches, use the Google AJAX Search API: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657570/google-search-from-a-python-app/1657597#1657597

Answer (score 10):

You should use the [Google API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/) for accessing the search. [Here's an example for python](http://dcortesi.com/2008/05/28/google-ajax-search-api-example-python-code/). Unutbu provided a link to an [older SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657570/google-search-from-a-python-app/1657597#1657597) which contains a corrected version of the same example code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import urllib, urllib2
import json

api_key, userip = None, None
query = {'q' : 'search google python api'}
referrer = "https://stackoverflow.com/q/3900610"

if userip:
    query.update(userip=userip)
if api_key:
    query.update(key=api_key)

url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&%s' % (
    urllib.urlencode(query))

request = urllib2.Request(url, headers=dict(Referer=referrer))
json = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(request))

results = json['responseData']['results']
for r in results:
  print r['title'] + ": " + r['url']
```

Comment: @Str1k3r: you can find the more information http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/reference.html#_intro_fonje

Answer (score 1):

A user agent string is indeed the way to go... pick any valid user agent from any common browser. In python 2.x, the following code should give you what you want:

```
import urllib2
r = urllib2.Request('http://www.google.com/')
r.add_header('User-Agent', 
             'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.8.1.19) '
             'Gecko/20081202 Firefox (Debian-2.0.0.19-0etch1)')
html = urllib2.urlopen(r).read()
```

Having said that, unutbu's recommendation to use the google search API (if you're looking to do searches) is by far the better way to go... avoids all that messy HTML parsing.

Comment: i tried Search  like that inurl:"Wops" but it's print errors message !!