# Fetching language detection from Google api

Tags: python, api

I have a CSV with keywords in one column and the number of impressions in a second column.

I'd like to provide the keywords in a url (while looping) and for the Google language api to return what type of language was the keyword in.

I have it working manually. If I enter (with the correct api key):
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/detect?v=1.0&key=myapikey&q=merde
I get:
{"responseData": {"language":"fr","isReliable":false,"confidence":6.213709E-4}, "responseDetails": null, "responseStatus": 200}
which is correct, 'merde' is French.

so far I have this code but I keep getting server unreachable errors:

```
import time
import csv
from operator import itemgetter
import sys
import fileinput
import urllib2
import json

E_OPERATION_ERROR = 1
E_INVALID_PARAMS = 2

#not working
def parse_result(result):
  """Parse a JSONP result string and return a list of terms"""

  # Deserialize JSON to Python objects
  result_object = json.loads(result)

  #Get the rows in the table, then get the second column's value
  # for each row
  return row in result_object

#not working
def retrieve_terms(seedterm):

  print(seedterm) 
  """Retrieves and parses data and returns a list of terms"""
  url_template = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/detect?v=1.0&key=myapikey&q=%(seed)s'
  url = url_template % {"seed": seedterm}


  try:
    with urllib2.urlopen(url) as data:
      data = perform_request(seedterm)
      result = data.read()
  except:
    sys.stderr.write('%s\n' % 'Could not request data from server')
    exit(E_OPERATION_ERROR)

  #terms = parse_result(result)
  #print terms
  print result

def main(argv):
  filename = argv[1]

  csvfile = open(filename, 'r')
  csvreader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

  rows = []
  for row in csvreader:
    rows.append(row)

  sortedrows = sorted(rows, key=itemgetter('impressions'), reverse = True)

  keys = sortedrows[0].keys()

  for item in sortedrows:
    retrieve_terms(item['keywords'])

  try:
    outputfile = open('Output_%s.csv' % (filename),'w')
  except IOError:
    print("The file is active in another program - close it first!")
    sys.exit()  
  dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(outputfile, keys, lineterminator='\n')
  dict_writer.writer.writerow(keys)
  dict_writer.writerows(sortedrows)
  outputfile.close()

  print("File is Done!! Check your folder") 

if __name__ == '__main__':
  start_time = time.clock()
  main(sys.argv)
  print("\n")
  print time.clock() - start_time, "seconds for script time"
```

Any idea how to finish the code so that it will work?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `referrer`, `userip` as described in [the docs](http://code.google.com/apis/websearch/docs/reference.html#_intro_fonje):

> An area to pay special attention to
>   relates to correctly identifying
>   yourself in your requests.
>   Applications *MUST* always include a
>   valid and accurate **http referer** header
>   in their requests. In addition, *we
>   ask, but do not require*, that each
>   request contains a valid **API Key**. By
>   providing a key, your application
>   provides us with a secondary
>   identification mechanism that is
>   useful should we need to contact you
>   in order to correct any problems. Read
>   more about the usefulness of having an
>   API key
>
> Developers are also *encouraged* to make
>   use of the **userip** parameter (see
>   below) to supply the IP address of the
>   end-user on whose behalf you are
>   making the API request. Doing so will
>   help distinguish this legitimate
>   server-side traffic from traffic which
>   doesn't come from an end-user.

Here's an example based on [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900610/access-to-google-with-python/3900666#3900666) to the question ["access to google with python"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3900610/4279):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json
import urllib, urllib2
from pprint import pprint

api_key, userip = None, None
query = {'q' : 'матрёшка'}
referrer = "https://stackoverflow.com/q/4309599/4279"

if userip:
    query.update(userip=userip)
if api_key:
    query.update(key=api_key)

url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/detect?v=1.0&%s' %(
    urllib.urlencode(query))

request = urllib2.Request(url, headers=dict(Referer=referrer))
json_data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(request))

pprint(json_data['responseData'])
```

#### Output

```
{u'confidence': 0.070496580000000003, u'isReliable': False, u'language': u'ru'}
```

Another issue might be that `seedterm` is not properly quoted:

```
if isinstance(seedterm, unicode):
   value = seedterm
else: # bytes
   value = seedterm.decode(put_encoding_here)
url = 'http://...q=%s' % urllib.quote_plus(value.encode('utf-8'))
```