# Google Search with Python

Tags: python, search

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657570/google-search-from-a-python-app------) I've learned how to google-search using Python 3. But in the example given there you can retrieve only the first 4 results. I need to retrieve information about the first 25 results (at least).

For each result I want to be able to get its:

- title
- url
- visible url (the visible url of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval is http://en.wikipedia.org/)
- site description

How can I do it?

**EDIT:** I'm using Python 3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This thread](http://groups.google.com/group/Google-AJAX-Search-API/browse_thread/thread/407a1bf2a2219117) should tell you what you need to know. In short, add `&rsz=large` to the URI to get eight results at a time, and `&start=8` (or 16, 24, etc.) gets you results starting with the indicated number. In no case can you get more than 64, and some searches allow only 8.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [JSON/Atom Custom Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html) and if necessary call it multiple times by using the `start` parameter to receive all results you are interested in.