# Unicode error trying to call Google search API

Tags: python, unicode, ascii, non-ascii-characters

I need to perform google search to retrieve the number of results for a query. I found the answer here - [Google Search from a Python App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657570/google-search-from-a-python-app/1657597#1657597)

However, for few queries I am getting the below error. I think the query has unicode characters.

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 28: ordinal not in range(128)

I searched google and found I need to convert unicode to ascii, and found below code.

```
def convertToAscii(text, action):
            temp = unicode(text, "utf-8")
            fixed = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', temp).encode('ASCII', action)
            return fixed
    except Exception, errorInfo:
            print errorInfo
            print "Unable to convert the Unicode characters to xml character entities"
            raise errorInfo
```

If I use the action ignore, it removes those characters, but if I use other actions, I am getting exceptions.

Any idea, how to handle this?

Thanks

== Edit ==
I am using below code to encode and then perform the search and this is throwing the error.

query = urllib.urlencode({'q': searchfor})

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot `urlencode` raw Unicode strings. You need to first encode them to UTF-8 and then feed to it:

`query = urllib.urlencode({'q': u"München".encode('UTF-8')})`

This returns `q=M%C3%BCnchen` which Google happily accepts.

Answer (score 0):

You can't safely convert [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) to ASCII. Doing so involves throwing away information (specifically, it throws away non-English letters).

You should be doing the entire process in Unicode, so as not to lose any information.

Comment: I am using query = urllib.urlencode({'q': searchfor}) and this is throwing error. Is there anyway to perform search on unicode itself.