# Printing accents and foreign characters using beautiful soup and python

Tags: python, html, parsing, unicode, beautifulsoup

I am scraping artists from discogs.com. I am unable to get the artist names as they appear on the page. E.g. artist Andrés appears as Andr\xe9s when I run my code.

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests
    import urllib2
    from itertools import chain
    import codecs

    headers = { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0' }

    all_artists = []

    result_pages = 1 #446

    def load_artists():
        for page in xrange(1, result_pages+1):
            url = url = 'https://www.discogs.com/search/?sort=have%2Cdesc&style_exact=House&genre_exact=Electronic&decade=2010&page=' + str(page)
            r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content.decode('utf-8'), 'html.parser')
            [all_artists.append(tag["title"]) for tag in soup.select('div#search_results h5 span')]

    load_artists()

    all_artists
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use python3, and you will no longer suffer from this

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is *wrong*, they are output as unicode, they print correctly when you ask Python to print them:

```
for a in all_artists:
    print(a)

...
Andrés
...
```

Comment: How can I store it in my list so that it's stored the same way it prints? I need to use these names in search queries

Comment: It's somewhat safer to store it as unicode.  It depends on which service you're searching with.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777764/unicode-error-trying-to-call-google-search-api) for an example.