# Python - How would I isolate and utilize the "answer" sometimes provided at the top of the page when something is searched in google

Tags: python, search

For example, when the phrase "Liam Neeson age" is searched,displayed in bold font, at the top of the page is "63 years (June 7, 1952)."  I have tried toying with the concepts presented from this previous question([Google Search from a Python App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657570/google-search-from-a-python-app)) with little success. I can only get links and not actual "answers."
Ideally I would like to be able to input a string and have it return the "answer" provided by google. If there is no "answer," as it is with some searches, I would like to be able to know that as well.

Comment: Have you tried checking if it's put into an identifiable div? I'd imagine google would assign some kind of identifier to it.

Answer (score 0):

Scrape with JavaScript-enabled browser like Firefox and [Selenium WebDriver](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/).

Answer (score -1):

This is an example in Java. Hope you can convert to python.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("Liam Neeson age");
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id="sbse0"]");
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id="sbse1"]");
```